# How come the derivative of $e^{i\theta} $ never vanish

Tags: complex-analysis

Since $e^{i\theta} $ where $0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi $ is paramaterization of the unit circle, I would expect its derivative to vanish, as the tangent line slope in some point definetly should be zero.

What's different here?

Comment: The derivitive of $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C \ \theta \mapsto e^{i\theta}$ at any point $z \in \mathbb C$ is $i \cdot f(z)$. As $f$ never vanishes and $i \neq 0$ so $f^\prime$ never vanishes. Whilst the real part of the derivative can vanish at points, it never does so at the same time as the complex part. This is akin to saying that $\cos \theta$ and $i\sin \theta$ can have vanishing derivatives, but not at the same time. These latter two functions give the real and complex parts of $e^{i \theta}$ respectively.

Comment: I think you're confusing the derivative with respect to $\theta$ and the derivative with respect to $x$.

Comment: Given a parameterization $p(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ of a curve, the derivative, $p'(t)=(x'(t),y'(t))$ doesn't give you "tangent *slope*" but a tangent *vector*. The "slope" is zero when the $y'(t)$ component itself vanishes (unless the $x'(t)$ component does, too, but nevermind that). So it is with $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$: the derivative is $-\sin\theta+i\cos\theta$, which isn't a "tangent *slope*", but a "tangent vector" (rather, a tangent complex number). The corresponding "slope" is zero when the imaginary component vanishes; namely, at odd multiples of $\pi/2$, as expected.

Comment: @Blue you could repost that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a parameterization $p(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ of a curve, the derivative, $p'(t)=(x'(t),y'(t))$ doesn't give you "tangent slope" but a tangent *vector*. The corresponding "slope" is zero when the $y'(t)$ component itself vanishes (unless the $x'(t)$ component also vanishes, but nevermind that).

So it is with $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$: the derivative is $ie^{i\theta}=-\sin\theta+i\cos\theta$, which isn't a "tangent slope", but a "tangent vector" (rather, a tangent *complex number*). Here, the corresponding "slope" is zero when the imaginary component vanishes; namely, at odd multiples of $\pi/2$ (that is, at the top and bottom of the circle), as expected. But the derivative of $e^{i\theta}$ as a whole never vanishes.

Comment: I see. Can you explain why the corresponding slope is zero when the $y'(t) $ component is zero?

Comment: @euler0.0: The tangent vector effectively breaks slope into components. "$\dfrac{\text{rise}}{\text{run}}$" becomes "$(\text{run},\text{rise})$" (or, in the complex context, "$\text{run} + i\;\text{rise}$"). Zero slope corresponds to $\text{rise}=0$; hence, when the second component of the tangent vector (or the imaginary component of the complex number) is zero.